# error in php programming

Tags: php, string, file

I have a text file write.txt:-**write.txt**

```
My name

jai hind

stack
```

I am getting the error in the following code at line 154 and 165 and the error is:-

> PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 11 in /home/sakshi/Desktop/syllabify/step2/Syll_script_1.php on line 154

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -2 in /home/sakshi/Desktop/syllabify/step2/Syll_script_1.php on line 165

**code:-**

```
$file1 = fopen("write.txt", "r");

$q=1;
while ( $line = fgets($file1) )
{

    $i=0;
    $arr = explode( "\n", $line );
    $q=$q+1;
    if(strcmp($arr[0],"." ) == 0)
    {
        $i=1;
        $q=$q-1;
        echo "\nposition of dot in write.txt:";
        echo "$i \t $q\n";
        break;
    }
}
fclose($file1);

if($i==0)
    echo $i;

while ( $q!=1 )
{

    $file_input=fopen("input.txt","r");
    $line = fgets($file_input);
    $p = strlen($line);
    echo $p;
    $a=2;
    if ($p == $a)
    {
        $m = $line[0];
        echo "$m\n";

        $l=0; $h=0;
        $filename=fopen("write.txt","r");
        $content=file("write.txt");

        for($i=0;$i<$u-1;$i++)
        {
            $arr=$content[$i];
            $length=strlen($arr); 

            for($j=0;$j<=$length;$j++)
            {
                if(strcmp($arr[$j],$m ) == 0)// line 154
                {
                    echo "\nYES PRESENT AT LINE NUMBER: ";
                    $h=$i+1;
                    echo "$h\n";
                    $l=$h+1;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        /********************************************************/             
        $arr3=$content[$l-2];// line 165
        $ar3=explode(" ",$arr3);
        $output_file=fopen("Result.txt","a");
        fwrite($output_file,$ar3[0]);
        fwrite($output_file," ");
        fclose($output_file);     
        $output_file=fopen("Result.txt","a");
        fwrite($output_file,$ar3[1]);
        fwrite($output_file," ");
        fclose($output_file);
        $ar3=str_replace("\n","",$ar3);
        $output_file=fopen("Result.txt","a");
        fwrite($output_file,$ar3[2]);
        fclose($output_file);
        /************************************************************/
        // put enter at the end of operation
        $output_file=fopen("Result.txt","a");
        fwrite($output_file,"\n");
        fclose($output_file);
        /**********************************************************/


    }
```

Comment: Can you post your full code ?

Comment: I copied the code, added two '}' and didn't got a error.

Comment: What is `$u`? This isn't whole code.

Comment: Have you initialized $m?

Comment: what u want exact output so we will understood bettter..

Comment: $u is the total number of lines in write.txt file

Comment: @jen , Yes I have initialized

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line:

```
for($j = 0; $j <= $length; $j++)
```

it should be

```
for($j = 0; $j < $length; $j++)
```

Without the '=' sign. Because with the equal sign the iteration will exceed the length of the string. Counting start at 0 until strlen()-1. Thus

```
$j < strlen();
```

Otherwise you should apply

```
$j <= strlen() - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if $arr is an array before access to an element.

Comment: $arr is a variable which has been assigned a string. But I am trying to access each character from $arr

Comment: also check if it is not null